# Finding a sequence of simple functions.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I am desperately trying to find a sequence of "simple" functions $f_k$ (linear combinations of characteristic functions) so that $(f_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is monotonically increasing and converges to $f(x)$ with $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}: x\mapsto \begin{cases} 
x^3 & x>0 \\ 
0  & \text{else}\\ 
\end{cases} $    (for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$).

Any suggestions? 
Thank you!

Comment: What have you tired?

Comment: Note: just try to construct $f_k \leq f$ with $f_k \to f$. You can then "a posteriori" make the sequence monotonically increasing.

Comment: I have been looking for a series that I could use, but couldn't find any... I have no clue how that could work. There's probably one special idea that works right? The $f_k\rightarrow f$ part is where i am stuck...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: think of a flight of stairs such that the treads just touch the graph of your function up to some $x$-coordinate $t$. Consider what happens when you make the widths of the treads smaller and smaller and keep increasing $t$.

Answer (score 0):

You can take in general $$f_n=\sum_{k=1}^{2^n\cdot n-1}2^{-n}k\cdot 1_{\left\{x\in\Bbb R\,:\, 2^{-n}k\le f(x)< 2^{-n}(k+1)\right\}}$$

Which, in this case, is $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x<2^{-n/3}\lor x\ge n^{1/3}\\ 2^{-n}\left\lfloor 2^n x^3\right\rfloor&\text{if }2^{-n/3}\le x< n^{1/3}\end{cases}$$